# How to get curl responses to get particular tag in php?

Tags: php, xml, curl, reference

Here my code is,

```
$ch = curl_init();     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($response);
```

I got response  like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rsp stat="ok">
    <mediaid>af11zj</mediaid>
    <mediaurl>http://yfrog.com/af11zj</mediaurl>
    </rsp>
```

How to get that mediaurl ? Any one help me? Thanks.

Comment: Try a xml parser. e.g: SimpleXML[http://php.net/simplexml]

Comment: i am asking to get that mediaurl only @Prisoner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have the response XML in `$response`:

```
<?php 
    $obj = simplexml_load_string($response);
    $mediaurl = (string) $obj->mediaurl;
?>
```